The definition of complex multiplication on K3 surfaces
I am reading this paper on the complex multiplication of K3 surfaces. It seems that this is only defined for complex K3 surfaces, or K3 surfaces over number fields. Is there a more general defintion applying to general fields, or both number fields and local fields?

The definition of a CM K3 surface is Hodge theoretic (the Mumford-Tate group of $H^2$ is abelian). To work over a more general field, you  would need another definition.

@DonuArapura Sorry, I haven't made myself clear. My question is exactly whether there is a more general definition. If not, is there some reason that we cannot do this?

One can replace the Mumford-Tate group by (the identity component of) the motivic Galois group (defined, e.g., using Andre's category of motives) to get a definition over an arbitrary field. Over local fields I think it is unlikely that there is a definition in terms of the Galois representation on the (etale) $H^2$: is there such a definition for CM abelian surfaces?

Over a field of characteristic zero, you can embed the field in $\mathbb{C}$, and then use Deligne's theorem that Hodge classes on K3 surfaces are absolutely Hodge to see that the answer is independent of the embedding.
